# Is there a way to validate a website as html4 using facebook scripts?

Tags: html, facebook-like, w3c-validation

I am using Facebook Like box and Facebook Comments on my website, but when I use the validator at http://validator.w3.org/ I get the following errors:

> general entity "appId" not defined and no default entity
>
> reference to entity "appId" for which no system identifier could be generated

I have seen that declaring the DOCTYPE as HTML5, these errors disappear but a bunch of other errors appear, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> general entity "appId" not defined and no default entity. reference to entity "appId" for which no system identifier could be generated

This usually means that you are using an `&` as data when it means "Start of character reference or entity". If you want to mean `&` say `&amp;`.

Comment: that fixed it! thanks a lot :) basically now I understand why the problem appeared in the first place, which is what I wanted, because as I said in my other comment the validation is no big deal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your HTML valid then I'd recommend using the `HTML5` doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>` this will be easier and it will be a lot nicer against plugins like the facebook like box, twitter stream etc.

However, why worry so much about HTML validation in the first place? It's no big deal.

Comment: I agree with you that it's no big deal, it's just that when I finish a project I like validating it just to make sure it will run as smooth as possible for everybody ( in this case the audience is more likely to be IE-ish )